# Replace in string from an array of modified strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to to take a string with [WORDS] within it and replace it with the contents of my array. Each item in the array should be wrapped `<strong>` elements.

For instance, I have this string.

```
let output = "This is my string body with [WORDS] within it.";
```

Now I have an array of words coming from an API endpoint and looks something like:

```
["test","word1","word2","word3"]
```

When the array comes in, I'm mapping it so that each array element can be wrapped in `<strong>`:

```
let words = api_words.map(function (word) {
  return `<strong>${word}</strong>`;
});
```

And then I pass my words to a replace function.

```
const formatted = string.replace("[WORDS]", words);
```

This does its job, but it's not rendering the `<strong>` as an actual HTML element.

So it looks (rendered) something like:

`This is my string body with <strong>test</strong>,<strong>word1</strong>....`

My return is:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {formatted}
    </React.Fragment>
}
```

Where I actually want the words to be bolded. How do I get react to actually render as html here? Or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: Well how is it being rendered? You are missing the important step.

Comment: Try this `const formatted = string.replace("[WORDS]", words.join(','));
`

Comment: @epascarello its rendered as <strong>test</strong>.... not actually bolded

Comment: How is it being rendered? What code is displaying it? You show you building the string which clearly is not the issue. The issue is the rendering of that string.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlText }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` - pass the string into this prop.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={formatted} ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the string literal so it is  `<span>{word} </span>`